# How to manipulate nested Json Data to de-Nest in java

Tags: java, json, gson

I have been looking solution for this problem but could not find one so asking this question.
I have some data which looks like this

```
{
       "data": [
         {
            "id": "5ab892c71810e201e81b9d39",
            "isSignedUpUsingFb": false,
            "personalInformation": {
                "firstName": "jio",
                "lastName": "g",
                "mobileNumber": "1234567890",
             },
            "accountBalance": 0,
           }
         ]
},
```

I want to write a java code to change the data structure to this

```
{
           "data": [
              {
                "id": "5ab892c71810e201e81b9d39",
                "isSignedUpUsingFb": false,
                "personalInformation_firstName":"jio",
                 "personalInformation_lastNAme":"g",
                 "personalInformation_mobileNumber":"1234567890",

                "accountBalance": 0,
               }
             ]
},
```

I am getting data from db as:

```
       @Override
        public List<User> getAllUsers() {
            logger.debug("entering all users method");
            List<User> allUsers=mongoOperations.findAll(User.class);
            for (User user : allUsers) {
                PersonalInformation info=user.getPersonalInformation());
                //manipulation code here
                user.setPersonalInformation(info);

            }
            return allUsers;
        }
```

So I want to write a logic so that i can convert the data in desired format and send it a return type. I know how to do same thing using J query but I want to do it in backend so any code for the above or any link will help.

Comment: Create new Array object "data" and add all required pairs to it.

Comment: can you give me some example

Comment: Basically you want to transform the `JSON` data from one format to another. But in the code snippet to retrieve data from database, I see that the `getPersonalInformation( )` returns the object of `PersonalInformation`. Can you show the its Java file? Also, have you written the code to convert `PersonalInformation` to `JSON` format?

Comment: its a java pojo file, having only properties with setters and getters

Comment: Then simply create another POJO class and set its values using the getters of the `PersonalInformation` class and finally convert it to `JSON` format.

Comment: thats is not the correct approach I belive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fond one solution which is very simple.So, basically when we create object for nested data we create it like this in JAVA.

```
public MyClass{

public String name;
public String contact;
public PersonalInformation personalinformation;
//setters and getter here
}
```

this will give me data as

```
"MyClass":{
"name": "abc",
"contact": "12345",
"personalInformation":{
"address": "asdasdasdad",
"city":"asdadad",
"pin": "asdfg",
}
}
```

so to remove this nested data we need to use `@JsonUnwrapped` which removes all the nested object and add it to our main object.

```
public MyClass{

    public String name;
    public String contact;
    @JsonUnwrapped
    public PersonalInformation personalinformation;
    //setters and getter here
    }
```

which will change the data structure as:

```
"MyClass":{
    "name": "abc",
    "contact": "12345",
    "address": "asdasdasdad",
    "city":"asdadad",
    "pin": "asdfg",
    }
```

for more reference you can check this link http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonUnwrapped.html
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple possible solutions. As Prabhav has mentioned the most intuitive one would be to create a new class and from there a object which can be transformed with a library to a JSON.

Variant one:

The new class would look like your data structure you want and access would be:

```
PersonalInformationJson pf = new PersonalInformationJson();
pf.setFirstName = info.getPersonalInformation_firstName
//... setting the rest of the object
//using jackson
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
try {
    // convert user object to json string and return it 
   String jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(u);
}
```

The other easier version to create a string, either per hand or use a lib:

```
// using org.json.JSONObject
  String jsonString = new JSONObject().put("personalInformation_firstName", info.value())
            .put("personalInformation_lastNAme", info.value());
```